# How to count values with multiple criterias

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two tables like below:

**Table 1: (element list)**

Element | Count

A        |

B        |

C        |

...

**Table 2: (element record)**

Date   | Element

1-1-2020  | A

1-1-2020  | A

4-7-2020  | B

6-9-2020  | C

...

I want to populate the column Count of table 1 with a counter of how many times each element (A,B,C [...]) appears in table 2 where the date is between two dates.

I want to achive this using Google Sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=COUNTIFS(Table2!A:A,">="&DATE([year],[month],[day]),Table2!A:A,"<="&DATE([year],[month],[day]),Table2!B:B,A2)
```

Presumably you could replace the DATE() functions with a reference to a cell that contained your start and end dates.